# while executing gem ... (ArgumentError) unknown encoding name - CP720

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I got now this strange error

```
while executing gem ... (ArgumentError)
unknown encoding name - CP720
```

When I want to run any gem commands  such as

```
   gem install rubygems-update
```

so when I goggled it  I found some one suggest to use this commands to Change encoding to 1252

```
C:\DevKit> chcp 1252
c:\DevKit> ruby dk.rb init
```

but after I used it I still got the same error , so **how i can solve this issue** ?????

Note : I'm using windows 7

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When did you do

`chcp 1252`

did you get

`Active code page: 1252`

as a confirmation?

If not then maybe you are not using one of the windows command prompts like the default one or the node.js command prompt.. Because this won't work on the Git command prompt (MINGW32).

After you get the confirmation of changing the code page, you can execute gem commands without the annoying unknown encoding name error.